# timer control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have a timer in vb.net and it's interval is 1000ms ,. i have placed in it's timer_tick event a code that will print screen the screen and save it to a database.

The problem is when i click outside of the form, or loosing the focus of the mouse to the form containing that timer/printscreen, the timer stops. As a result the printscreen also stops.

here are it's properties:

```
generate member = true
interval = 1000
modifiers = friend
```

I will appreciate any reply or tip regarding this problem ,. thank you.,

Comment: Is the Enabled property set to True?

Comment: i programatically set it to true.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint everywhere you Stop/disable the timer, and see if they get hit when the form loses focus

Answer (score 1):

A simple test creating a form with a `Timer` with

`Interval = 1000,
Enabled = True`

and the following code in the form

```
Dim i As Integer = 0

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Debug.WriteLine(i)
    i += 1
End Sub
```

continued to `Tick` (and produce output) regardless of whether or not the form had the focus.

Are you sure that you are not calling `Stop()` or setting `Enabled` to `False` anywhere in your code?

I'd recommend putting a breakpoint anywhere you call `Stop()` or change `Enabled`; then you can see if these lines are being executed when the form loses focus.

Comment: i'm calling a stop, and enable to false in the click event of button stop.